# Kooboo CMS - not working from IIS

Tags: kooboo

I just downloaded KoobooCMS - I'm new to it.

When I run it from IIS - it works fine with the ASP development server. If I convert `Kooboo_CMS/Kooboo_CMS` to an application - then go to `http://localhost/Kooboo_CMS` - I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
```

How can I get this working? Thanks.

Comment: More explicit details of HTTP errors can almost always be found in the Event Viewer / Windows Logs / Application.  The entry description usually includes sufficient detail to understand the problem and fix it.  This level of detail is not passed back to the browser to avoid giving hackers information that may be useful in an attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to give the permission to iis_usr in the folder where your cms code resides.

Comment: FYI I've since changed to the excellent Composite C1 CMS (it's essentially free - not commercial which is why I didn't investigate it at first)